# ${Env.CATALINA_HOME} does not exit in openshift

Tags: mysql, tomcat, ant, openshift, opengts

I have a question which is related to openshift online and I am using a Tomcat7 cartridge,Mysql5.5 and Ant Cartridge 0.1.And I am trying to deploy OpenGTS project to openshift but when I open a SSH session and I try to run this command "ant all" it shows that "BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/openshift/568e35812d52717d1f000122/app-root/runtime/repo/build.xml:66:
/var/lib/openshift/568e35812d52717d1f000122/app-root/runtime/repo/${Env.CATALINA_HOME} does not exit"
I am worry about that,I deleted the tomcat application and created again but it is showing same error.please help me.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `<property environment="env"/>` is present at the top of the script.

Also `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable is defined in the system.

Use `${env.CATALINA_HOME}` instead of `${Env.CATALINA_HOME}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and yes <property environment="env"/> is present in build.xml file.and also CATALINA_HOME is defined in the system.but where I have to put the ${env.CATALINA_HOME}?

Comment: @shafqatali, updated answer. Just replace it where you have `${Env.CATALINA_HOME}`

Comment: Thanks Rao,I tried that one but now it is showing same error with ${env.CATALINA_HOME} does not exit.and it has in my build.properties.xml file

Comment: @shafqatali, why dont you show the script? or run in debug mode `ant -debug` and update the question with more details specific to the issue.

Comment: Can you also add line `<echo message="Catalina Home is ${env.CATALINA_HOME}">` to see if the value is set. Check the command - `env|sort|grep CATALINA_HOME`

Comment: Sorry for delay and I am working on openshift online,So I tried the above commands but nothing is happened.

Comment: Did you try `env|sort|grep CATALINA_HOME` this on terminal? not in build script.

Comment: That means you have not defined `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable which it is already mention in the answer asking to define. To set `export CATILINA_HOME=/your/absolute/path`

Comment: thanks,but in openshift what would be my path?Or I have to put jbossews-2.0

Comment: Hi,Rao here is my build.xml file:https://github.com/shafqatali404/OpenGTS_2.6.0/blob/master/build.xml